# Hector (Cassandra) Serialize Anomaly

Tags: java, cassandra, hector

Q. I am using hector (cassandra client) and storing UTF8 type values in columns, on the client side I am using hector's StringSerializer to serialize/ deserialize values. It works fine for normal strings (only alphanumeric chars)…but when there are non-alphanumeric chars (like —> , ; / ) it serializes it ..but is unable to deserialize..anyone else has seen this issue ?

Comment: turned out to be a coding error, https://github.com/rantav/hector/issues/274#issuecomment-2072268